# install4j tooltip freezes when java 7 attached in mediaSets

Tags: java, install4j

In installer created with install4j when you move mouse over tooltip (for example radio-button tooltip), the installer freezes (hangs) for some time.
After long investigation I found (what is for me quite strange) that it is associated with attached java version. When in mediaSet I have java 6 everything works fine, as soon as I attach java 7 (windows-amd64-1.7.0_51) the installer hangs for the first time when I move mouse over any tooltip.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: installer with windows-amd64-1.7.0_45 also hangs

Comment: Can you get a thread dump with jstack while the UI is hanging?

Comment: I have two processes:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqfgii63jjymreq/1.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2ctobdf2prq0rt/2.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread dump shows that the AWT stalls in

```
sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.isPixFmtSupported(int, int)
```

This seems to happen for some graphics cards. This is the bug in the JRE:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6477756

It's targeted to be resolved in Java 9.

The workaround is to set the system property

```
-Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true
```

for the installer.